# MailEnable on server with no DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, smtp, email

I want to test MailEnable on a vmware server that is not connected to a DNS. I am not allowed to install a dns on the vmware server. Is it possible to test MailEnable in this environment?

Answer (score 1):

If MailEnable has the ability to forward to a smarthost, and you have a smarthost available to you, then this should be possible.

Comment: You will need to configure MailEnable to send all mail to your smarthost by IP address or hosts entry.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can not. Mail relies hevaily on DNS. You can possibly do a low level test with the hosts file, but any more advanced functions rely on DNS being available.